# string causes "reference not set to instance of object"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I have this code, which is reading data from a databse, then assigns a url from the web.config file to a string.

```
bool isRequestCI = false;
            if (context.Request.QueryString["RequestCI"] != null)
            {
                isRequestCI = Convert.ToBoolean(context.Request.QueryString["RequestCI"].ToString());
            }
            string GetFileInfo;
            if (isRequestCI)
            {
                GetFileInfo = "select [FileName],FileExtension,MD5Hash from ElementCIBinaryAttachments where CIBinaryFileID = " + binaryFileID;
            }
            else
                GetFileInfo = "select [FileName],FileExtension,MD5Hash from CaseFileBinaryAttachments where BinaryFileID = " + binaryFileID;
            SqlCommand comGetFileInfo = new SqlCommand(GetFileInfo, cnGetFile);
            SqlDataReader drFileInfo;
            cnGetFile.Open();
            drFileInfo = comGetFileInfo.ExecuteReader();
            string fileName = "";
            string fileExtension = "";
            string MD5Hash = "";
            while (drFileInfo.Read())
            {
                fileName = drFileInfo["FileName"].ToString().Trim();
                fileExtension = drFileInfo["FileExtension"].ToString().Trim();
                MD5Hash = drFileInfo["MD5Hash"].ToString().Trim();
            }
            drFileInfo.Close();
            cnGetFile.Close();

            string MD5PathRequestCI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CIUploadedFiles"].ToString() + MD5Hash.Substring(0, 3) + @"\" + MD5Hash.Substring(3, 3) + @"\" + MD5Hash.Substring(6, 3) + @"\" + MD5Hash.Substring(9);
```

however, it is causing an exception at `string MD5PathRequestCI` saying "reference not set to an instance of an object and I have no clue why. I never used to do that or am I missing something?

Comment: Is this value actually set? `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CIUploadedFiles"]`. Also, for debugging purposes concatenate each of those on their own lines instead of at once to see where the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CIUploadedFiles"]` is returning null. Make sure the value "CIUploadedFiles" exists in your config file.

Comment: Ah thank you. I just checked again and apparently the "CIUploadedFiles" was actually suppose to be "CIUploadedFilesStorage". I must have gotten confused and used the dir name instead of the web.config key name

Answer (score 2):

Check the web.config file.  Verify that you have an appSettings entry with key "CIUploadedFiles" in the  section of your config.  The  section is inside the root  element:

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
  <add key="CIUploadedFiles" value=""/>
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thank you. And yes that was the problem, I got confused because I was looking at the directory folder name instead of the web.config key name